# How to set window always on top of any other applications

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window

I have a JFrame which needs to be always on top of the other application. For this I am using `setAlwaysOnTop()` method of [Window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)) class.

Here is my code :

```
class Test1 extends JFrame {

    public Test1() {
        initComponents();
        setTitle("Top Window");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }


    private void initComponents() {
        jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("I am a top most window");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }                     

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
}
```

This works fine with some of the other application such as notepad, explorer etc, i.e. when my application is above notepad everything works fine.

[image]

But when my java application goes above any application that is already on top such as **task manager**. Then the method `setAlwaysOnTop()` doesn't works.

[image]

What I need is any way through which I can make my application always on top.

I have also searched many other related posts on stackoverflow but none seems to answer my question. I have also tried other ways such as overriding the `windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)` method

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        toFront();
        //requestFocus();
        //requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

but this also doesn't worked.

Is there any other way through which I can may my **JFrame always on top of every other application** except in case of full screen applications.

Comment: This is OS dependent and you don't have any control over it.  When two windows are set to `alwaysOnTop` it is unpredictable (from Java) which one will actually be the higher

Comment: JFrame pretty ignores setAlwaysOnTop(), this is about basics JDialogs funcionalities

Comment: *"But when my java application goes above any application that is already on top such as task manager. Then the method setAlwaysOnTop() doesn't work"*  ..and that surprises you?!?  It surprises me that anyone would expect an x-plat plug-in to do much 'fighting' when it comes to to being be 'always on top'..

Comment: @MadProgrammer then is there any other way to achieve this, apart from using native api.

Comment: @PankajPrakashh I can't see a native solution solving the problem either

Comment: @MadProgrammer means there isn't any solution to the problem. But I think there is a solution in C#.

Comment: @PankajPrakashh From my understanding of Windows, it's very, very picky about these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the operating system. In general, you can't guarantee that your window will always be on top when it comes to native windows, nor should you. The task manager is always-on-top for good reasons.

I remember that some versions of Vista and older Windows systems allowed that and the native and Java windows ended up fighting for focus.

Comment: I know the task bar is always-on-top for some good reasons. But what if I need my JFrame to be **on top** of other applications that are already on top. Suppose I am creating a desktop application that needs to be on top for some security reasons or accessibility reason or some other reason.

Comment: @PankajPrakashh Security reasons is why the task manager is on top. Regardless, there is no Java code that will let you do that on all OS. You can try to write native functions for that. I will note that it actually *is* possible on Windows (at least 7 or below) to have the window always-on-top, but it will also take the focus all the time, so it's somewhat malicious because you lose the interaction with the rest of the windows.